# Why in Django Rest Framework remove object still appears on a list?

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

After removing object it is still in response data.

`/api/premises/premises/4`

returns

```
{
   "detail": "Not found."
}
```

but `/api/premises/premises/`

*returns*

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "image": "/product/lb-gallery-main.jpg",
        "owner": "owner@lebernardin.com",
        "name": "Le Bernardin",
        "description": "Le Bernardin to francuska restauracja z owocami morza na Manhattanie w Nowym Jorku. Gilbert Le Coze i jego siostra Maguy Le Coze otworzyli restaurację w Paryżu w 1972 roku, pod nazwą Les Moines de St. Bernardin.",
        "country": "Poland",
        "city": "Gdynia",
        "postcode": "80-209",
        "address": "Starowiejska 1",
        "tags": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "image": "naws.com/product/Union-Oksford.jpg",
        "owner": "admin@admin.com",
        "name": "dadad",
        "description": "dada",
        "country": "dada",
        "city": "dada",
        "postcode": "dad",
        "address": "dadadada",
        "tags": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "image": "196290008887877_5616210528952631689_n.jpg",
        "owner": "admin@admin.com",
        "name": "Sebastian Wrzałek",
        "description": "adadada",
        "country": "dadad",
        "city": "adada",
        "postcode": "dada",
        "address": "dadadadaddd",
        "tags": []
    }
]
```

Weird that it is not displayed on Django Admin. Also I am using Docker, after restart it is updating list and not showing deleted item. When I checked Database table directly data is correntc meaning item is removed correctly. I am thinking where it comes from and why it is cached somehow?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
    redis:
        image: redis
        command: redis-server
        ports:
            - "6379:6397"
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        command: >
            sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db &&
                   python manage.py check_connection &&
                   python manage.py migrate &&
                   python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
        environment:
            - DB_HOST=db
            - DB_NAME=app
            - DB_USER=postgres
            - DB_PASS=sspassword
        depends_on:
            - db
        env_file:
            - .env
    db:
        image: postgis/postgis:9.6-2.5-alpine
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=app
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sspassword
```

Edit.

views.py

```
class PremisesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Manage premises in database"""
    lookup_field = 'id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'premises_id'
    serializer_class = serializers.PremisesSerializer
    queryset = Premises.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Retreive the premises for auth user"""
        try:
            # TODO create wrapper for header
            if(self.request.META['HTTP_X_SOURCE_WEB']):
                return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        except KeyError:
            return self.queryset

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        """Return appropriate serializer class"""
        return self.serializer_class

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Create a new premises"""
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def menu(self, request, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        menu = Menu.objects.filter(premises=instance, is_default=True)
        serializer = MenuProductsSerializer(menu, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializers.py

```
class PremisesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer a premises"""
    image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.email')
    location = serializers.HiddenField(default=Point(1,1))

    class Meta:
        model = Premises
        fields = '__all__'

        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: Show the view that returns this response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `get_queryset` which is as follows:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    """Retreive the premises for auth user"""
    try:
        # TODO create wrapper for header
        if(self.request.META['HTTP_X_SOURCE_WEB']):
            return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    except KeyError:
        return self.queryset
```

The problem is that in the `except` block you are **directly** returning `self.queryset`. As the queryset is actually defined on the class it has already been evaluated in some **previous** request. If you see the default implementation of `get_queryset` has the following lines:

> ```
> if isinstance(queryset, QuerySet):
>     # Ensure queryset is re-evaluated on each request.
>     queryset = queryset.all()
> ```

The line `queryset = queryset.all()` is of our concern here. What this does is (as the comment already indicates) it makes sure that the QuerySet is re-evaluated on each request. Hence you should change your implementation to:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    """Retreive the premises for auth user"""
    # TODO create wrapper for header
    if self.request.META.get('HTTP_X_SOURCE_WEB') is not None: # Instead of try-except use .get() which will return `None` if the header is not set
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
    return self.queryset.all()
```

Comment: Working just fine, becuase I was always using  `return super(ViewSet, self).get_queryset()` I didn't know it works this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a browser to view `/api/premises/premises/` then you may be viewing a cached version of that page. Try a `Ctrl-R` to reload a fresh version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is in the view of the endpoint `/api/premises/premises/4`. Can you provide more details about the view and its serializer?

Also, I noticed that the trailing slash (`/`) is missing from the endpoint `/api/premises/premises/4` in contrast to the endpoint `/api/premises/premises/`. This could trigger a redirect http call in case that the trailing slash has been defined in urls.py.

Comment: I've updated post, adding trailing slash output same result.